# Flask app throws 'Not Found' error when run in localhost

Tags: python, localhost, flask-restful

I have created a simple python Flask app names app.py and it contains the below code:

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/query_example')
def query_example():
    return 'Todo...'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

However. when I run app.py and access "http://127.0.0.1:5000/query-example" in my web browser, I get the following error: -

> **Not Found** 
>   The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

What I really want to display when I access the url is "Todo..."

My program runs without an error, so I do not understand what has gone wrong with the code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is '/query_example', but you type in '/query-example' to your URL.

Try typing "http://127.0.0.1:5000/query_example" into your browser instead.

Comment: Still getting the same result

Comment: That's odd, I just ran your script, and that fix is working for me.... let me look into other possible problems.

Comment: My localhost was already occupied by another task. When I killed the tasks, my flask app started running without a problem. Thanks for the help! :)